# filling 2d char array and accessing each element

Tags: c++

It's my first question in stack overflow so if there is some mistakes sorry about that. I'm trying to fill a 2d char array and then access each letter. I complied my code, there is no error but when I try to run it doesn't work. Here it's my code.

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<stdlib.h>

using namespace std;


int main() {

    char ch[] = "Welcome text in a separate line.";
    char strWords[5][7];
    int counter = 0;
    int a = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(ch); i++) {

        if (ch[i] == ' ') {
            strWords[counter][a] = '\0';
            counter++;
            a = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            strWords[counter][a] += ch[i];
            a++;
        }

    }

    for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {

        for (int a = 0; a <= 7; a++) {
            cout << strWords[i][a] << "  ";

        }
    }




    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `strWords` is uninitialized, containing random garbage. Then you add characters to that garbage - the result is different garbage. `strWords[counter][a] += ch[i];` should probably be `strWords[counter][a] = ch[i];`

Comment: Valid indexes into `strWords` are 0 through 4 and 0 through 6. The program is accessing `strWords[5][a]` and `strWords[i][7]`, whereupon it exhibits undefined behavior by way of accessing an index out of bounds.

Comment: In your first for loop, you are iterating using `sizeof(ch)`. Sizeof is a function that gets the size of an object in bytes - which isn't exactly what you are looking for here. You should get the length of the string with strlen or ch.length(), depending on if you are using C or C++!

Comment: @BrentGeorge It so happens that in this case, `sizeof(ch)` is in fact the length of the string, or close enough; to be precise, it's `strlen(ch)+1`, the extra +1 for the terminating NUL character.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I get it mistakes but valid indexes. What should I do to fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

A few things wrong with your code

```
int main() {

    char ch[] = "Welcome text in a separate line.";
    // char strWords[5][7]; <<<=== i would change to be larger that you need, just in case
    char strWords[20][20];
    int counter = 0;
    int a = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(ch); i++) { // sizeof is wrong, you need strlen

        if (ch[i] == ' ') {
            strWords[counter][a] = '\0';
            counter++;
            a = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            //strWords[counter][a] += ch[i];
            strWords[counter][a] = ch[i]; // you do not need to try to concatenate, you are already walking down the buffer with 'a'
            a++;
        }

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++) { // use 'counter' as it has the number of lines
       // since you 0 terminated the string you do not need to walk character by character

         cout << strWords[i] << "  ";

    }


    return 0;
}
```

You are also not detecting and terminating the last word (since there is no space after it). I will leave that to you. The code I show does not print the word 'line.'

You should really have tests to make sure you do not overflow the length or number of words.

Plus you should ideally use `std::string` and `std::vector`

Note - if, for experimentation, you do want to walk through char by char to output the strings you should look for the terminating '0' character and exit the inner loop